# PhoneGap - Apparently cannot send data using AJAX

Tags: php, android, ios, json, cordova

I'm trying to send data from a PhoneGap application to a PHP page using the following code:

```
//Login Function
$("#login").click(function(){

    var cognome=$("#cognome").val();
    var password=$("#password").val();
    var dataString="cognome="+cognome+"&password="+password+"&login=";
    if($.trim(cognome).length>0 & $.trim(password).length>0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: dataString,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").html('Connecting...');},
            success: function(data){
                if(data=="successPaziente")
                {
                    window.location.href = "home.html";
                    localStorage.email=cognome;
                    localStorage.login="true";
                }
                else if(data=="successMedico")
                {
                    window.location.href = "homeMedico.html";
                    localStorage.email=cognome;
                    localStorage.login="true";
                }
                else if(data="failed")
                {
                    alert("I dati inseriti non sono corretti");
                    $("#login").html('Login');
                }
                sendDataToChart();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});

function sendDataToChart() 
{
    var cognome=$("#cognome").val();
    var password=$("#password").val();
    var dataString="cognome="+cognome+"&password="+password+"&login=";
    if($.trim(cognome).length>0 & $.trim(password).length>0)
    {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: url3,
            data: dataString,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false
        });
        window.location.href = url3;
    }
    return false;
};
```

The "Login" function works fine, but, when sendDataToChart() is called, no data seem to be send to "url3".

url3 contains:

```
<?php    
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    $link = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'myusername', 'mypsw' );
    if ( !$link ) {
      die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() );
    }

    // Select the data base
    $db = mysql_select_db( 'my_db', $link );
    if ( !$db ) {
      die ( 'Error selecting database \'my_db\' : ' . mysql_error() );
    }

   $cognome=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['cognome'])));
   $password=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['password'])));
   echo $cognome;
   echo $password;
?>
```

as you can see, I try to print on the screen the content of "$cognome" and "$password", but nothing appears.

Comment: Is this script working in browser ?

Comment: no, is not working

Comment: please share the error you are seeing in console/network tab.

Comment: Where can I get access to the console/network tab? Because to me seems that the value of $cognome and $password are not being send to url3 (since nothing is printed on the screen).

Comment: press F12 in chrome. it will open up developer tools. Refresh the page and
have a look at console and network tab. there must be an error message or code in one of that tab.